# XDoclet classpath missing J2EE classes

Tags: java, ant

While running my ant file i get the following errror

```
[ejbdoclet] XDoclet classpath missing J2EE classes
[ejbdoclet]     at xdoclet.modules.ejb.EjbDocletTask.validateOptions       (EjbDocletTask.java:86)
[ejbdoclet]     at xjavadoc.ant.XJavadocTask.execute(XJavadocTask.java:89)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
[ejbdoclet]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.RunTargetTask.execute(RunTargetTask.java:48)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute   (MacroInstance.java:378)
[ejbdoclet]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForDelegate.doSequentialIteration(ForDelegate.java:228)
[ejbdoclet]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForDelegate.doTheTasks(ForDelegate.java:253)
[ejbdoclet]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForDelegate.execute(ForDelegate.java:213)
[ejbdoclet]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.For.execute(For.java:166)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:37)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:30)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:382)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:107)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
```

[ejbdoclet] Caused by: Make sure the jar file containing the javax.ejb.EntityBean class is on the classpath specified in the  that defined ejbdoclet. These classes are needed in order to generate correct output.
    [ejbdoclet]     at xdoclet.DocletTask.checkClass(DocletTask.java:513)
    [ejbdoclet]     at xdoclet.modules.ejb.EjbDocletTask.validateOptions(EjbDocletTask.java:83)
    [ejbdoclet]     ... 39 more
    [ejbdoclet] --- Nested Exception ---
    [ejbdoclet] Make sure the jar file containing the javax.ejb.EntityBean class is on the classpath specified in the  that defined ejbdoclet. These classes are needed in order to generate correct output.
    [ejbdoclet]     at xdoclet.DocletTask.checkClass(DocletTask.java:513)
    [ejbdoclet]     at xdoclet.modules.ejb.EjbDocletTask.validateOptions  (EjbDocletTask.java:83)
    [ejbdoclet]     at xjavadoc.ant.XJavadocTask.execute(XJavadocTask.java:89)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
    [ejbdoclet]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.RunTargetTask.execute(RunTargetTask.java:48)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:64)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:378)
    [ejbdoclet]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForDelegate.doSequentialIteration(ForDelegate.java:228)
    [ejbdoclet]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForDelegate.doTheTasks(ForDelegate.java:253)
    [ejbdoclet]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForDelegate.execute(ForDelegate.java:213)
    [ejbdoclet]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.For.execute(For.java:166)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:37)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:30)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:382)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:107)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets  (DefaultExecutor.java:40)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    [ejbdoclet]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)

what does it mean and howcan i get rid of it.

Do i need to  add external jar to it or i need to make some changes in the properties file